# glewInit() fails on macOS

Tags: c++, opengl, osx-lion

So I have a piece of code that runs fine on ubuntu machine, but fails to do so on xcode or via terminal. I'm trying to run it on xcode, but it fails on main with:

"Use of undeclared identifier glewInit; did you mean glutInit?"
"Too few argument to function call, expected 2, have 0"

The code is lengthy is been written by my professor and it runs on ubuntus. But with the errors, I'm thinking that the reasons is...well, underclared identifier, include is missing. So, after googling I figured out that glewInit is part of the glew library -> so I downloaded the code and installed it on my machine with following:

make
sudo -s
make install

which were successfully installed into my /usr/include/GL. Now, when i type into xcode #include  or just #include , the compiler throws that glew.h is not found (though i can i see the file myself in the usr/include/GL).

Here is the code:

```
#include "include/Angel.h"

// The rotation  around z axis
GLfloat  Theta = 0.0; // Angle (in degrees)
GLfloat  step = 0.01; // Incremental
GLuint  locTheta;  
enum { CW = 0, CCW = 1};
int direction = CW;  // Direction

//Scale along x and y axes
GLfloat ScaleFactor[2] = {1.0, 1.0};
GLuint locScale;

const int NumPoints = 4;
void init();
void display( void );
void reshape( GLsizei w, GLsizei h );
void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y );
void mouse( int button, int state, int x, int y );
void idle( void );
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// OpenGL initialization
void init()
{
    // Vertices of a unit square centered at origin, sides aligned with axes
    vec4 points[] = {
        vec4( -0.5, -0.5,  0, 1.0 ), //v1
        vec4(  0.5, -0.5,  0, 1.0 ), //v2
        vec4( -0.5,  0.5,  0, 1.0 ), //v3
        vec4(  0.5,  0.5,  0, 1.0 )  //v4
    };

    // RGBA colors
    vec4 colors[] = {
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
        vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
        vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // blue
    };

    // Create and initialize a buffer object
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points) + sizeof(colors), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(points), points );
    glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), sizeof(colors), colors );

    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader_rot.glsl", "fshader_rot.glsl" );
    glUseProgram( program );

    // set up vertex arrays
    GLuint vPosition = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
    glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
               BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );

    GLuint vColor = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vColor" ); 
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( vColor );
    glVertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
               BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(points)) );

    // The location of shader uniform variables
    locTheta = glGetUniformLocation( program, "theta" );
    locScale = glGetUniformLocation( program, "scale" );

    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void display( void )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glUniform1f( locTheta, Theta );
    glUniform2fv( locScale, 1, ScaleFactor );

    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, NumPoints);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void reshape( GLsizei w, GLsizei h )
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    // Scale the square to avoid stretching
    if (w > h) ScaleFactor[0] = (float)h/w;
    if (w < h) ScaleFactor[1] = (float)w/h;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    switch( key ) {
    case 033: // Escape Key
    case 'q': case 'Q':
        exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
        break;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void mouse( int button, int state, int x, int y )
{
    if ( state == GLUT_DOWN ) {
        switch( button ) 
        {
        case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:    
            direction = CCW;  
            break;
        case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:   
            direction = CW;  
            break;
        }
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void idle( void )
{
    // Animate the rotation
    if (direction == CW)    
        Theta += step;
    else
        Theta -= step;

    if ( Theta > 360.0 ) {
        Theta -= 360.0;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );
    glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );
    glutCreateWindow( "Rotating Color Square" );

    glewInit();
    init();

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutReshapeFunc( reshape );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );
    glutMouseFunc( mouse );
    glutIdleFunc( idle );

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I have Lion 10.7.4 and xCode 4.2.1

Comment: can you show whats in Angel.h.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

glewInit() call (and the includes, of course) is not necessary on MacOS, so you might just exclude it this way:

```
#ifndef __APPLE__
glewInit();
#endif
```

The same with includes.

Now with the unresolved symbols. You have to include MacOSX's native GL headers:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#  include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#  include <OpenGL/glext.h>
#else /// your stuff for linux
#  include "GL/GL.h"
.... whatever
#endif
```

OpenGL is a core technology for OSX, not an "extension", as in Linux/X Window. So just include the OpenGL and GLUT framework to your XCode project and hopefully it should build and work.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it seems strange, that development on MacOS is somewhat easier :)    Don't hesitate to upvote the answer, btw :)

Comment: Minor correction to this answer: The name of the header file on Mac OS is `<OpenGL/gl.h>`. Note the lower case `gl.h`, compared to the upper case `GL.h` in the answer. In addition, to get access to GL3+ features, the header to include would be `<OpenGL/gl3.h>` instead.

Comment: @RetoKoradi  thanks, fixed that. Maybe I got used to the OSX default case insensitivity mode for HFS.

Comment: OMG +1000000 if I could.  Spent the last three hours trying to figure out why I couldn't get my new framework to build on my Mac.  Makes perfect sense when I use my brain for a change. lol.  THANK you.