# What are reasons for function call to address NULL?

Tags: function, nullpointerexception, linker, segmentation-fault, call

My OpenGL program builds with help of CMAKE under OSX and Ubuntu 14.04. It runs smooth under OSX, but first call to GL function: `glDeleteBuffers()` results in a segmentation fault under Linux. Stepping through the disassembly in Eclipse-CDT showed:

```
mov 0x2200df(%rip),%rax        # 0x69a840 <__glewDeleteBuffers>
mov -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
add $0x14,%rdx
mov %rdx,%rsi
mov $0x1,%edi
callq *%rax
    glDeleteBuffers( 1, &normalBufferID );
```

Problem is; tracing register values shows the `callq` to `*%rax` is a call to `NULL`! OpenGL context is 4.3 core as requested.

*Under which circumstances does such a runtime error happen?*

---

**Solution:** because I'm using GLFW, too. I added that snippet:

```
if (glewInit() != GLEW_NO_ERROR)
{
    cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW... " << endl; 
    return -1;
}
```

after `glfwInit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) from the code snippet (`__glewDeleteBuffers`) - are you calling `glewInit()` before you call any OpenGL functions? Doing this loads the appropriate OpenGL function pointers from your OpenGL context. Forgetting this is the only way I've had an OpenGL function pointer be null (on both Windows and Linux). See [this tutorial under "Function Loading" for more details](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Getting%20Started%20with%20OpenGL.html).

[According to this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11213354/2507444) OSX doesn't require `glewInit()` because OpenGL is a core part of OSX (I have no experience with it), which would explain why you don't crash on OSX.

[Here is the GLEW documentation that goes over calling and checking the result of glewInit()](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html).